# Slow performance when unpacking bits for a tensor layer in tensorflow

Tags: javascript, bitmap, bit-manipulation, tensorflow.js

I'm working with data that comes over a WebSocket connection with a starcraft 2 client to obtain image data from a game that is in progress. In some cases, the image data maybe be set with a format of 1 bit per pixel. When this happens I need to "unpack" the bits from each byte in the response (1 byte => 8 bits). This is done in the code below:

```
function unpackbits(uint8data) {
  const results = new Uint8Array(8 * uint8data.length)
  let byte
  let offset
  for (let i = 0; i < uint8data.length; i++) {
    byte = uint8data[i]
    offset = (8 * i)
    results[offset + 7] = ((byte & (1 << 0)) >> 0)
    results[offset + 6] = ((byte & (1 << 1)) >> 1)
    results[offset + 5] = ((byte & (1 << 2)) >> 2)
    results[offset + 4] = ((byte & (1 << 3)) >> 3)
    results[offset + 3] = ((byte & (1 << 4)) >> 4)
    results[offset + 2] = ((byte & (1 << 5)) >> 5)
    results[offset + 1] = ((byte & (1 << 6)) >> 6)
    results[offset + 0] = ((byte & (1 << 7)) >> 7)
  }
  return results
}
```

This gets fed into a tensor like so:

```
 static unpack_layer(plane) {
    //Return a correctly shaped tensor given the feature layer bytes.//

    const size = point.Point.build(plane.getSize()) // { x, y }

    if (plane.getBitsPerPixel() === 1) {
      data = unpackbits(data)
      if (data.length !== (size.x * size.y)) {
        // This could happen if the correct length isn't a multiple of 8, leading
        // to some padding bits at the end of the string which are incorrectly
        // interpreted as data.
        data = data.slice(0, size.x * size.y)
      }
    }

    data = tf.tensor(data, [size.y, size.x], 'int32')
    return data
}
```

In one of my tests, this code get's run 1900 times and takes 0.0737s to execute.

This is very slow.

For comparison, the equivalent functionality in python takes 0.0209s to run 1900 times. The python code looks like this:

```
  def unpack_layer(plane):
    """Return a correctly shaped numpy array given the feature layer bytes."""

    size = point.Point.build(plane.size) # {x, y }
    data = np.frombuffer(plane.data, dtype=Feature.dtypes[plane.bits_per_pixel])

    if plane.bits_per_pixel == 1:
      data = np.unpackbits(data)
      if data.shape[0] != size.x *  size.y:
        # This could happen if the correct length isn't a multiple of 8, leading
        # to some padding bits at the end of the string which are incorrectly
        # interpreted as data.
        data = data[:size.x * size.y]
    return data.reshape(size.y, size.x)
```

In short, it takes the javascript version roughly 4x as long as the python version.

I'll be looking at the numpy unpackbits documentation as that seems to be doing something much more efficient than my own approach -

However, I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts as to how I could better optimize my own unpackbits function or better yet a way to have TensorFlow do that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like tensorflow.js does not have a bitwise AND function, so suspect doing the work within tensorflow.js will require some coding gymnastics...

One suggestion, though, is to create an array of 256 Uint8Array's of size 8, and pre-populate it with the complete list of 8 byte translations.  This greatly reduces the repeated calculations for a byte stream that will likely have repeated values in the range of 0 - 255.  Eg, the first entry in the precomputed array represents the unpacking of byte 0, and therefore is a Uint8Array of size 8 populated with 0's, the next entry is another Uint8Array of size 8 populated with 00000001, etc all the way to the entry representing byte 255 with is a Uint8Array of size 8 populated with all 1's.

Then, when unpacking, simply make use of the typed array [.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) method to copy the precomputed unpacked representation into the `results` Uint8Array...

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**  Created a number of variants of the unpacking algorithm to test the performance of inline calculations vs memory lookup and was surprised at the results using Chrome.  Some of the optimizations of the V8 compiler are non-intuitive...

The differences in the versions...

- unpackbits [FAST]:  From the original question and this is the bar by which the others variations are compared.
- unpackbits1 [FAST]:  Modified by...

  - Specifying "|0" after every integer.
  - Using the increment unary op ( "++" ) rather adding increments to the `offset` index of the `result` array.
  - Replacing the calculation of bit masks with the actual value.  (Ie, rather than `1 << 5`, the function used `32`.)
- unpackbits1a [FAST]:  The same as unpackbits1, except...

  - Kept the calculation of bit masks rather than integer values.  (Ie, using `1 << 5` rather than `32`, as in the original question.)  *Counter intuitively, this produces a bit faster result!*
- unpackbits1b [SLOWER]:  The same as unpackbits1a, except...

  - The `offset` is not recomputed every time inside the loop.  Ie, `offset = 0|0` is initially set, and then thereafter `offset` is only incremented within the loop.  So, `offset = ( (8|0) * i )` is no longer calculated for every byte.  *Counter intuitively, this produces a slower result!*
- unpackbits2 [SLOWEST]:  This is the memory lookup option that I recommended above.  *Counter intuitively, this implies that typed array memory operations are much slower than calculating the results as in `unpackbits`!*
- unpackbits3 [SLOWER]:  This is the memory lookup option that I recommended above, with the following change.

  - Rather than used the the typed array `.set` method, this version set the eight bytes one-by-one. *Counter intuitively, this implies that the typed array `.set` method is slower (at least for eight bytes) than individually setting the values!*
- unpackbits4 [SLOWER]:  This variation of the algorithm was on par with the original, and was a variation of the memory lookup option.  But, rather than 256 individual Uint8Array's, this combined all the pre-calculated results into a single Uint8Array of length 256 * 8.  And it did not make use of the typed array `.set` method.
- unpackbits5 [SLOWER]:  Same as unpackbits4, except...

  - Rather than using the unary "++" on the index into the lookup table, it calculated the index for each of the 8 bytes being copied.  As expected, calculating the index every time was slower than using the unary "++" operator.

Here are the tests.  BEWARE that this builds an initial array of 10M random bytes, and then runs each unpack algorithm on this same data.  On my workstation, the test runs in less than 5 seconds.

```js
var lookupTable = initializeLookupTable();

function initializeLookupTable() {
  let lookup = new Array( 256 );
  let v = new Uint8Array( 1 );
  for ( let i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
    v[ 0 ] = i;
    lookup[ i ] = unpackbits( v );
  }
  return lookup;
}

var lookupTable4 = initializeLookupTable4();

function initializeLookupTable4() {
  let lookup = new Uint8Array( 256 * 8 );
  let v = new Uint8Array( 1 );
  for ( let i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
    v[ 0 ] = i;
    let temp = unpackbits( v );
    lookup.set( temp, i * 8 );
  }
  return lookup;
}

function unpackbits(uint8data) {
  const results = new Uint8Array(8 * uint8data.length)
  let byte
  let offset
  for (let i = 0; i < uint8data.length; i++) {
    byte = uint8data[i]
    offset = (8 * i);
    results[offset + 7] = ((byte & (1 << 0)) >> 0)
    results[offset + 6] = ((byte & (1 << 1)) >> 1)
    results[offset + 5] = ((byte & (1 << 2)) >> 2)
    results[offset + 4] = ((byte & (1 << 3)) >> 3)
    results[offset + 3] = ((byte & (1 << 4)) >> 4)
    results[offset + 2] = ((byte & (1 << 5)) >> 5)
    results[offset + 1] = ((byte & (1 << 6)) >> 6)
    results[offset + 0] = ((byte & (1 << 7)) >> 7)
  }
  return results
}

function unpackbits1(uint8data) {
  const results = new Uint8Array(8 * uint8data.length)
  let byte;
  let offset;
  for (let i = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++) {
    byte = uint8data[i]|0
    offset = (8 * i)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 128)>>7)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 64)>>6)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 32)>>5)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 16)>>4)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 8)>>3)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 4)>>2)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 2)>>1)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & 1)>>0)|0;
  }
  return results
}

function unpackbits1a(uint8data) {
  const results = new Uint8Array(8 * uint8data.length)
  let byte;
  let offset;
  for (let i = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++) {
    byte = uint8data[i]|0;
    offset = (8 * i)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 7))>>7)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 6))>>6)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 5))>>5)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 4))>>4)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 3))>>3)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 2))>>2)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 1))>>1)|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & 1)|0;
  }
  return results
}

function unpackbits1b(uint8data) {
  const results = new Uint8Array(8 * uint8data.length)
  let byte;
  let offset = 0|0;
  for (let i = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++) {
    byte = uint8data[i]|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 7))>>7)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 6))>>6)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 5))>>5)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 4))>>4)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 3))>>3)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 2))>>2)|0;
    results[offset++] = ((byte & (1 << 1))>>1)|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & 1)|0;
  }
  return results
}

function unpackbits2( uint8data ) {
  const result = new Uint8Array( 8 * uint8data.length );
  for ( let i = 0|0, ri = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++, ri += 8 ) {
    result.set( lookupTable[ uint8data[ i ] ], ri );
  }
  return result;
}

function unpackbits3( uint8data ) {
  const result = new Uint8Array( 8 * uint8data.length );
  let ri = 0|0;
  for ( let i = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++ ) {
    //result.set( lookupTable[ uint8data[ i ] ], ri );
    let lv = lookupTable[ uint8data[ i ] ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 0|0 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 1|0 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 2|0 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 3|0 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 4|0 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 5|0 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 6|0 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lv [ 7|0 ];
  }
  return result;
}

function unpackbits4( uint8data ) {
  const result = new Uint8Array( 8 * uint8data.length );
  let ri = 0|0;
  for ( let i = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++ ) {
    let li = (uint8data[ i ] * 8)|0;
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li++ ];   
  }
  return result;
}

function unpackbits5( uint8data ) {
  const result = new Uint8Array( 8 * uint8data.length );
  let ri = 0|0;
  for ( let i = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++ ) {
    let li = (uint8data[ i ] * 8)|0;
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li+1 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li+2 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li+3 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li+4 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li+5 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li+6 ];
    result[ ri++ ] = lookupTable4[ li+7 ];   
  }
  return result;
}


// Test

console.log( 'Building array of 10,000,000 test values.' );
let buffer = new ArrayBuffer( 10000000 );
let testArray = new Uint8Array( buffer );
for ( let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++ ) {
  testArray[ i ] = Math.floor( 256 * Math.random() );
}
console.log( 'Finished building test values.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits.' );
console.time('u');
let u = unpackbits( testArray );
console.timeEnd('u');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits1.' );
console.time('u1');
u = unpackbits1( testArray );
console.timeEnd('u1');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits1.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits1a.' );
console.time('u1a');
u = unpackbits1a( testArray );
console.timeEnd('u1a');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits1a.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits1b.' );
console.time('u1b');
u = unpackbits1b(testArray );
console.timeEnd('u1b');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits1b.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits2.' );
console.time('u2');
u = unpackbits2( testArray );
console.timeEnd('u2');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits2.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits3.' );
console.time('u3');
u = unpackbits3( testArray );
console.timeEnd('u3');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits3.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits4.' );
console.time('u4');
u = unpackbits4( testArray );
console.timeEnd('u4');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits4.' );

console.log( 'Starting unpackbits5.' );
console.time('u5');
u = unpackbits5( testArray );
console.timeEnd('u5');
console.log( 'Finished unpackbits5.' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll try this out soon and report back tomorrow.

Comment: I tried out your method and got the following results:

CACHE (new)
0.0757,
0.0754,
0.0738,
0.0777,
0.0784,
0.0774

ave = 0.0764


CALC (old)
0.0703,
0.0740,
0.0712,
0.0719
0.0712,
0.0751

ave = 0.0723


I should clarify this was run for the same 1900 trials test.

So I guess it's slightly slower to look it up versus calculating it on the spot. I really thought it would've been faster though!

Comment: Ditto.  Take a look at `unpackbits1a` in my edited answer, as it includes a few mods to your version that accelerate performance.

Comment: I'll have some results to share with you tonight. But holy crap what a gold mine of neat optimizations!  I would never have even thought to think about what type of number is being used for the array index value - (8|0 * i) - is black magic without that consideration. As soon as I'm done with the refactoring I'm currently in the middle of I'll re-run these tests using `unpackbits1a`. I'm really excited to try it out.

Comment: Yeah, am interested in how `unpackbits1a` fairs in your specific scenario... Of course, the slow down might be during the generation of the tensor!  Liberal use of `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` will help narrow down the bottlenecks.

Comment: unpackbits1a:
0.0681
0.0706
0.0703
0.0739
0.0702
0.0730

average  = 0.07101

Comment: `unpackbits1a` is consistently the fastest method, and to your point highlights that the real culprit here is reading in the data to tensor flow, looking at this now from the angle of removing the need for a tensor here

Comment: In the same style you used, I'll post a number of solutions with a sample test. The goal for me now is to reshape the unpacked data without using tensor flow.

Comment: Hey, so while I was writing out some different methods to reshape the unpacked bits, I noticed we don't get the same result when just unpacking the bits from [255].

unpackbitsOriginal([255]) => Uint8Array(8) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

unpackbits1a([255]) => Uint8Array(8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

You see this too right?

Comment: Ugh... Looks like precedence issue with the "|0"... Fixing the algorithms... and it looks like unpackbits1a is only marginally faster than unpackbits1.

Comment: Hey, I wrote up a response for you in an answer to the post, for better formatting. I just wanted to share what I had found.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but am kicking myself as I got hung up on the need for bitwise operators in tensorflow in order to convert a byte stream into a bit stream, per the original question.  Simple use of integer division and modulus can do the trick too!

In short, the algorithm by example is thus.  Given byte stream of [ 92 ]...

- Divide and mod by 16, resulting in 2 bytes, namely [ 5 ] and [ 12 ] respectively.
- Interleave these results into a tensor [ 5, 12 ].
- Take each of those values, and divide and mod by 4, resulting in [ 1, 3 ] and [ 1, 0 ].
- Interleave these results into a tensor [ 1, 1, 3, 0 ].
- Divide and mod by 2, resulting in [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] and [ 1, 1, 1, 0 ].
- Interleave into [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ] which is binary for 92.

Below are two versions of the same algorithm.  One in tensorflow and one in pure javascript.

```js
function tfDaC( stream ) {
  
  const stream8bit = tf.tensor( stream, undefined, 'int32' );
  
  console.time('in-tf');
  const stream4bitHi = tf.div(stream8bit, tf.scalar(16, 'int32' ));
  const stream4bitLo = tf.mod(stream8bit, tf.scalar(16, 'int32' ));
  const stream4bit = tf.stack([stream4bitHi, stream4bitLo],1).flatten();

  const stream2bitHi = tf.div( stream4bit, tf.scalar(4, 'int32' ));
  const stream2bitLo = tf.mod(stream4bit, tf.scalar(4, 'int32' ));
  const stream2bit = tf.stack([stream2bitHi, stream2bitLo],1).flatten();

  const stream1bitHi = tf.div(stream2bit, tf.scalar(2, 'int32' ));
  const stream1bitLo = tf.mod(stream2bit, tf.scalar(2, 'int32' ));
  const stream1bit = tf.stack([stream1bitHi, stream1bitLo],1).flatten().toBool();
  console.timeEnd('in-tf');
  
  return stream1bit.dataSync().buffer;
}


function jsDaC( stream ) {

  let result = new ArrayBuffer( stream.byteLength * 8 );

  let buffer32 = new Uint32Array( result );  // Pointer to every 4 bytes!  
  for ( let i = 0; i < stream.byteLength; i++ ) {
    let byte = stream[ i ];
    buffer32[ (i * 2) |0 ] = ( byte / 16) |0;
    buffer32[ (i * 2 + 1) |0 ] = ( byte % 16 ) |0;
  }
  
  let buffer16 = new Uint16Array( result );  // Pointer to every 2 bytes!  
  for ( let i = 0; i < buffer32.length; i++ ) {
    let byte = buffer32[ i ];
    buffer16[ (i * 2) |0 ] = ( byte / 4) |0;
    buffer16[ (i * 2 + 1) |0 ] = ( byte % 4 ) |0;
  }
  
  let buffer8 = new Uint8Array( result );  // Pointer to every 4 bytes!  
  for ( let i = 0; i < buffer16.length; i++ ) {
    let byte = buffer16[ i ];
    buffer8[ (i * 2) |0 ] = ( byte / 2 ) |0;
    buffer8[ (i * 2 + 1) |0 ] = ( byte % 2 ) |0;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log( 'Generating array of 1M bytes' );
let buffer = new ArrayBuffer( 1000000 );
let testArray = new Uint8Array( buffer );
for ( let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++ ) {
  testArray[ i ] = Math.floor( 256 * Math.random() );
}

let result;

console.log( 'Begin tensorflow divide & conquer test with 1M bytes.' );
console.time( 'tf' );
result = tfDaC( testArray );
console.timeEnd( 'tf' );
console.log( `End tensorflow test with 1M bytes resulting in array of ${result.byteLength} bytes` );

console.log( 'Begin javascript divide & conquer test with 1M bytes.' );
console.time( 'js' );
result = jsDaC( testArray );
console.timeEnd( 'js' );
console.log( `End javascript test with 1M bytes resulting in array of ${result.byteLength} bytes` );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

The tensorflow performance was terrible on my workstation.  I had to reduce the byte stream down to 1M bytes as my GPU was throwing memory errors at my previous test levels of a 10M byte stream.  And even then at only 1M bytes, a handful of tests ranged from 1236ms to 1414ms.  Not sure why it was so slow.  Could possibly be the coercion of the numbers to int32 which might be adding a lot of overhead, as my understanding is that GPU's are generally built primarily for floating point operations.  And marshalling the data onto and off of the GPU consumes some time too.  Maybe it's worthwhile to try to convert this function to a floating point only function rather than int32...?!  Maybe a grabbed a poor version of tensorflow.js...?!  Be interested to hear how it runs in your NodeJS configuration...

On the other hand, the javascript version for 1M bytes ranged from 30ms to 42ms, almost 2 orders of magnitude(!) faster than the GPU.  But still, when extrapolating these results to 10M bytes, this algorithm is still slower than all the other previous algorithms...

So not sure if this helps.  It might simply help eliminate tensorflow as an option, although it might still be worthwhile trying floats rather than int32, but am not very hopeful...

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. I wouldn't have known you could extract these values in the two ways presented.

Also, when I ran your code in my node environment I got the following:
tf - 46.574ms
js - 10.590ms

Something is definitely up with your tensorflow setup... I'm on windows 10 and I'm doing things in a pretty standard way. As I understand the framework and its purpose, tensorflow is good at utilizing the GPU for operations that can be batched. So I guess bit fiddling like this doesn't lend itself well for that kind of computing.

Comment: Also, thank you for your feedback, the introspection has been fruitful, it's hard to know exactly where the bottlenecks exist without taking a finer look at each method being invoked and timing it, but right now I have a better understanding on which things I can improve and which I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

This response is a continuation of the comment chain under @Jon Trent's answer.

EDIT: Include TensorFlow comparison for the reshaping portion.

I'm profiling the performance of two unpacking bits methods; unpackbits1a, and unpackbits (original). I am also profiling the different methods for reshaping the data to a NxM grid, where N is probably the same as M. Here's what I got:

```
function unpackbits1a(uint8data) {
  const results = new Uint8Array(8 * uint8data.length)
  let byte;
  let offset;
  for (let i = 0|0, n = uint8data.length; i < n; i++) {
    byte = uint8data[i]
    offset = ((8|0) * i);  // The "|0" on this line cut's the time almost in half!
    results[offset++] = (byte & ((1|0) << (7|0)))>>7|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & ((1|0) << (6|0)))>>6|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & ((1|0) << (5|0)))>>5|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & ((1|0) << (4|0)))>>4|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & ((1|0) << (3|0)))>>3|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & ((1|0) << (2|0)))>>2|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & ((1|0) << (1|0)))>>1|0;
    results[offset++] = (byte & (1|0));
  }
  return results
}

function unpackbits(uint8data) {
  const results = new Uint8Array(8 * uint8data.length)
  let byte
  let offset
  for (let i = 0; i < uint8data.length; i++) {
    byte = uint8data[i]
    offset = 8 * i
    results[offset + 7] = ((byte & (1 << 0)) >> 0)
    results[offset + 6] = ((byte & (1 << 1)) >> 1)
    results[offset + 5] = ((byte & (1 << 2)) >> 2)
    results[offset + 4] = ((byte & (1 << 3)) >> 3)
    results[offset + 3] = ((byte & (1 << 4)) >> 4)
    results[offset + 2] = ((byte & (1 << 5)) >> 5)
    results[offset + 1] = ((byte & (1 << 6)) >> 6)
    results[offset + 0] = ((byte & (1 << 7)) >> 7)
  }
  return results
}


function unpackbitsToShape1(uint8data, shape = [1, 1]) {
  var data = unpackbits(uint8data)
  const dims = [shape[0] | 0, shape[1] | 0]
  const result = new Array(dims[0])
  let temp
  const width =  0 | dims[1]
  for (let i = 0 | 0; i < dims[0]; i++) {
    temp = new Array(dims[1])
    for (let j = 0| 0; j < dims[1]; j++) {
      temp[j] = data[uint8data[i * width + j]]
    }
    result[i] = temp
  }
  return result
}

function unpackbitsToShape2(uint8data, shape = [1, 1]) {
  var data = unpackbits(uint8data)
  const dims = [shape[0] | 0, shape[1] | 0]
  const result = new Array(dims[0])
  const width = dims[1]
  let offset
  for (let i = 0 | 0; i < dims[0]; i++) {
    offset = (width * i)
    result[i] = data.slice(offset, offset + width)
  }
  return result
}

function unpackbitsToShape3(uint8data, shape = [1, 1]) {
  const dims = [0 | shape[0], 0 | shape[1]]
  const result = new Array(dims[0])
  let position = 0 | 0
  const smallCount = 0 | (uint8data.length % dims[0])
  const bigCount = 0 | (uint8data.length - smallCount)
  const bigByteChunk = 0 | (bigCount / dims[0])
  const bigBitWidth = 0 | 8 * bigByteChunk
  const smallByteChunk = 0 | (smallCount / dims[0])
  const smallBitWidth = 0 | 8 * smallByteChunk
  if (smallCount) {
    let big
    let small
    let odd
    let temp
    for (let i = 0 | 0; i < dims[0]; i++) {
      temp = new Uint8Array(dims[1])
      odd = i % 2
      big = unpackbits(uint8data.subarray(position, position + bigByteChunk))
      position += bigByteChunk
      if (odd) {
        temp.set(small.subarray(smallBitWidth, 8), 0)
        temp.set(big, smallBitWidth)
        result[i] = temp
      } else {
        temp.set(big, 0)
        small = unpackbits(uint8data.subarray(position, position + 1))
        position++
        temp.set(small.subarray(0, smallBitWidth), bigBitWidth)
        result[i] = temp
      }
    }
    return result
  }
  for (let i = 0 | 0; i < dims[0]; i++) {
    // console.log('unpacking: ', uint8data.subarray(position, position + bigByteChunk))
    result[i] = unpackbits(uint8data.subarray(position, position + bigByteChunk))
    position += bigByteChunk
  }
  return result
}

var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs')
tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
function unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow(uint8data, shape) {
  return tf.tensor(unpackbits(uint8data), shape, 'int32')
}

var test64by64 = new Uint8Array(512)
for (let i = 0; i < test64by64.length; i++) {
  test64by64[ i ] = Math.floor(256 * Math.random());
}
var test84by84 = new Uint8Array(882)
for (let i = 0; i < test84by84.length; i++) {
  test84by84[ i ] = Math.floor(256 * Math.random());
}
var test100by100 = new Uint8Array(1250)
for (let i = 0; i < test100by100.length; i++) {
  test100by100[ i ] = Math.floor(256 * Math.random());
}

function assert(condition, errMsg) {
  if (!condition) {
    console.error(errMsg)
  }
}

console.log('********* 64 x 64 *********\n\n')
console.log('Starting unpackbits1a.');
console.time('u1a');
var foo = unpackbits1a(test64by64);
console.timeEnd('u1a');
console.log('Finished unpackbits1a.');
console.log('Starting "unpackbits"');
console.time('u-orig');
foo = unpackbits(test64by64);
console.timeEnd('u-orig');
console.log('Finished unpackbits.');


console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape1"');
console.time('u1');
foo = unpackbitsToShape1(test64by64, [64, 64])
console.timeEnd('u1');
assert(
  foo.length === 64 && foo[0].length === 64,
  'foo.length === 64 && foo[0].length === 64'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape1.');


console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape2"');
console.time('u2');
foo = unpackbitsToShape2(test64by64, [64, 64])
console.timeEnd('u2');
assert(
  foo.length === 64 && foo[0].length === 64,
  'foo.length === 64 && foo[0].length === 64'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape2.');

console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape3"');
console.time('u3');
foo = unpackbitsToShape3(test64by64, [64, 64])
console.timeEnd('u3');
assert(
  foo.length === 64 && foo[0].length === 64,
  'foo.length === 64 && foo[0].length === 64'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape3.');

console.log('\nStarting "unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow"')
console.time('u-tensor')
foo = unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow(test64by64, [64, 64])
console.timeEnd('u-tensor')
console.log('Finished unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow.');


console.log('\n\n********* 84 x 84 *********\n\n')
console.log('Starting unpackbits1a.');
console.time('u1a');
foo = unpackbits1a(test84by84);
console.timeEnd('u1a');
console.log('Finished unpackbits1a.');
console.log('Starting "unpackbits"');
console.time('u-orig');
foo = unpackbits(test84by84);
console.timeEnd('u-orig');
console.log('Finished unpackbits.');


console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape1"');
console.time('u1');
foo = unpackbitsToShape1(test84by84, [84, 84])
console.timeEnd('u1');
assert(
  foo.length === 84 && foo[0].length === 84,
  'foo.length === 84 && foo[0].length === 84'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape1.');


console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape2"');
console.time('u2');
foo = unpackbitsToShape2(test84by84, [84, 84])
console.timeEnd('u2');
assert(
  foo.length === 84 && foo[0].length === 84,
  'foo.length === 84 && foo[0].length === 84'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape2.');

console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape3"');
console.time('u3');
foo = unpackbitsToShape3(test84by84, [84, 84])
console.timeEnd('u3');
assert(
  foo.length === 84 && foo[0].length === 84,
  'foo.length === 84 && foo[0].length === 84'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape3.');

console.log('\nStarting "unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow"')
console.time('u-tensor')
foo = unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow(test84by84, [84, 84])
console.timeEnd('u-tensor')
console.log('Finished unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow.');


console.log('\n\n********* 100 x 100 *********\n\n')
console.log('Starting unpackbits1a.');
console.time('u1a');
foo = unpackbits1a(test100by100);
console.timeEnd('u1a');
console.log('Finished unpackbits1a.');
console.log('Starting "unpackbits"');
console.time('u-orig');
foo = unpackbits(test100by100);
console.timeEnd('u-orig');
console.log('Finished unpackbits.');


console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape1"');
console.time('u1');
foo = unpackbitsToShape1(test100by100, [100, 100])
console.timeEnd('u1');
assert(
  foo.length === 100 && foo[0].length === 100,
  'foo.length === 100 && foo[0].length === 100'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape1.');


console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape2"');
console.time('u2');
foo = unpackbitsToShape2(test100by100, [100, 100])
console.timeEnd('u2');
assert(
  foo.length === 100 && foo[0].length === 100,
  'foo.length === 100 && foo[0].length === 100'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape2.');

console.log('Starting "unpackbitsToShape3"');
console.time('u3');
foo = unpackbitsToShape3(test100by100, [100, 100])
console.timeEnd('u3');
assert(
  foo.length === 100 && foo[0].length === 100,
  'foo.length === 100 && foo[0].length === 100'
)
console.log('Finished unpackbitsToShape3.');

console.log('\nStarting "unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow"')
console.time('u-tensor')
foo = unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow(test100by100, [100, 100])
console.timeEnd('u-tensor')
console.log('Finished unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow.');
```

I don't know how different the browser's execution environment is than node, but results *seem* more stable in node. Here's what I get:

```
********* 64 x 64 *********


Starting unpackbits1a.
u1a: 0.513ms
Finished unpackbits1a.
Starting "unpackbits"
u-orig: 0.189ms
Finished unpackbits.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape1"
u1: 0.434ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape1.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape2"
u2: 0.365ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape2.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape3"
u3: 0.590ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape3.

Starting "unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow"
u-tensor: 0.508ms
Finished unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow.


********* 84 x 84 *********


Starting unpackbits1a.
u1a: 0.222ms
Finished unpackbits1a.
Starting "unpackbits"
u-orig: 0.425ms
Finished unpackbits.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape1"
u1: 0.622ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape1.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape2"
u2: 0.303ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape2.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape3"
u3: 0.388ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape3.

Starting "unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow"
u-tensor: 0.175ms
Finished unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow.


********* 100 x 100 *********


Starting unpackbits1a.
u1a: 1.502ms
Finished unpackbits1a.
Starting "unpackbits"
u-orig: 0.018ms
Finished unpackbits.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape1"
u1: 1.631ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape1.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape2"
u2: 0.072ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape2.
Starting "unpackbitsToShape3"
u3: 0.159ms
Finished unpackbitsToShape3.

Starting "unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow"
u-tensor: 0.052ms
Finished unpackBitsToShapeTensorflow.
```

Comment: Given that the time spent processing the data with TensorFlow is about the same as it is if I were to reshape that data on my own, I no longer think TensorFlow is the issue here. In fact, my test time goes up in my project code if I use my own function in place of the call to tf.tensor with the shape argument.

Comment: Kinda feeling dumb at the moment... When I was looking at your example code, I got hung up that bitwise operators were required to split the byte into 8 bytes.  But simple div and mod will do the trick.  Am posting another answer that's a pure tensor flow solution that takes the byte stream and converts into a boolean "bit" byte stream.

Comment: Odd how some of the results arn't linearly consistent with the number of bytes... On a more fundamental note, what is the driver behind reshaping the resulting unpacked bytes into a two dimensional array?  In a lot of cases, it's sometimes best to leave the data as a single dimension and simply treat it as a two dimensional array when necessary by calculating the linear index based on the (x,y) coordinates much as you've done in the shaping routines...

Comment: Yeah, I ran these tests a handful of times and certain (larger) sizes seem to be faster than other (smaller) ones, I don't know why that happens. I can only imagine that it's an aspect of small dimensions; 64 x 64, 100x100. 

Driver for 2d shape: I need image layers for convolutional processing. But, to your point about flat data that acts like a 2d grid, I've thought about that and it feels like I'd just be putting off the calculation till later - is there a benefit there?

Comment: Ah, so the end result is to have the image with a bit depth of 1 at the head end of a CNN.  Right, so in your initial post you're already taking a linear array and reshaping to a tensor2d, which is likely the fastest means to marshall the data to the GPU.  Do you have a feel for how much of the 0.07s is actually associated with the unpacking the original image vs the marshalling of the data to the GPU?